# oracle udump trc file size issue

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, jvm

My project uses oracle db hosted on unix machine. The issue is that the trace files generated at udump location have loggers from my custom code as well. (custom code loggers are from java callouts which are loadjava on the db).
Now every time i use that module the udump folder is flooded by 3 new trc files which have default oracle logs as well as my custom code logs.
I want to disable the logs that are generated from my code.
Till now i have tried to write a custom log4j.properties and loadjava it n use it for my code, in that prop file i have used file and console handlers pointed to custom location on unix machine other than udump location. But still the custom logs are coming only in udump location and there are no logs at the new location which i tried from the prop file.
I tried disabling the logging.trace=false in the logging.properties file of the oracle jvm.
I have checked a few sql queries which can disable session trace. It identifies around 70 sessions. I just want to disable java logs, i would like to know if its possible to find the session that my java logs use and disable the trace for it.

I am using oracle 9i version and java 1.4 version.
Need to disable the custom logs from coming to the udump location. Also the solution should be implementable generally as my application goes multiple environments like test env, stage env, prod env..
Any hint would be very helpful.

Comment: are these logs written from console output and if so whats the value of java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level?

Comment: have no value for consoleHandler.level.Can i mention it in the custom log4j.properties file?Just for details the log is not from system.out logs but these are logs which appear on a log file and also are appearing on udump file.For file handler level do i have to mention in logging.properties file or any file.Also db re-start is a long process that i need to follow might take 2 days.

Comment: I have tried with the ConsoleHandler.level as ALL as well as OFF, in both cases the logs are appearing in the Udump location